# large data processing error in JSON and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

i have one php page with request data from other page using JSON

i have ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "getdata.php",
             cache:false,
             data:"list_id="+ encodeURIComponent(cont_list),
             dataType:'json',
             success: function(json)
             {
            var foo = json.foo;
            $(foo).addClass('innertxt');
            $('#all_users').append(foo);
         }
```

after data is processed in 2nd php file it send back in bellow symtax

```
$return["foo"] =$val;

print stripslashes(json_encode($return));
```

$val is variable with data. it works fine for small amount of data but if records are in thousands like 5,000 to 50,000 or more it didn't work and it shows bellow error in firebug

```
script stack space quota is exhausted
```

how can i process and get result of big data.

Thanks

Comment: [Script stack space exhausted firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000211/script-stack-space-exhausted-firefox)

Comment: how do you manage this much amount of data in the front end?

Comment: is the error presented if you do not process the DOM in the success function (e.g. if the success function is empty)? If json.foo a large DOM structure, or you are receiving a lot of DOM elements and you are processing in a script? Try removing the success function's code line by line to see which exactly produces an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could compress your json tp gzip format data.
The json string is text, so after compression, you will get a very much smaller response.
About how to compress your response data in php, please check [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)